# Banach inverse operator theorem

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces, inverse

Let $T : X \rightarrow Y$ be a bounded linear bijection between two Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$.
Than the inverse operator $T^{-1} : Y \rightarrow X$ is also (linear and) bounded and

> $ \exists K >0 $ such that $||T(x)||\geq K ||x|| \qquad \forall x \in X$

Why isn’t this last property already guaranteed by the boundedness of $T$? I mean $||T(x)||\leq ||T|| \ ||x|| \quad \forall x \in X \implies -||T|| \ ||x|| \leq ||T(x)||\leq ||T|| \ ||x|| $, so why don’t simply put $K = -||T||$?

Comment: But $-\|T\|\not>0$

Comment: lol good point. I can't believe I didn't see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that $T^{-1}$ bounded if if there exists a finite $K \geq 0$ such that $\forall x \in X$, we have that $ norm(T x) \leq K norm(x)$ $\forall x \in X$.

In the statement above (∃K>0 such that ||T(x)||≥K||x||∀x∈X), it is $\leq$ not $\geq$.

If $norm(T x) \geq - norm(T) norm(x)$ then even if the sympol is $\leq$ less than or equal, then  $K = - norm(T)$ is negative and so doesn't statify the requirement that it must be greater than zero.